# Android : Paypal Express checkout integration not working

Tags: android, paypal

I am integrating paypal express checkout to my android studio project.

Added dependencies `compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'`
Added below code in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Finally calling paypal fragment using below code

```
BraintreeFragment mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(PayActivity.this, tokenValue);
                PayPalRequest request = new PayPalRequest(amount.getText().toString())
                        .currencyCode("USD");
                PayPal.requestOneTimePayment(mBraintreeFragment, request);
```

But the app is not redirecting to the paypal screen. 
Can you guys please let me know what else i need to do to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: @surendra did u got any solution?

Comment: Check your package name . It should not be capitalized or any number should be there . One suggestion would be to change your app package name to simple  ((i.e) com.own.example) name to check if its working now or not .

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.myhomework.myhomework.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

your data android:scheme = should be equal to ua package name.braintree.. and if your packagename or package id has capitalised letters please use small